# Getting java.security.cert.CertificateException, however the certificate is imported into the truststore

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore

I always receive a

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

exception, however i've imported the certificate to my trusrstore. Here my Setup:

I'm using a small HTTPS Server based on `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer`. I've create a keystore with a self signed certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias myCert -keystore keystore.jks -storepass myPass -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

I'm passing the path and password to the keystore as VM arguments `Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/tmp/truststore.jks` `Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=myPass`

If I run `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.101:4443` I can see that it uses the right certificate.

To trust the certificate on client site, I've exported the certificate from the server keystore and imported it to the client truststore:

```
  keytool -export -alias myCert -file myCert.crt -keystore keystore.jks
  keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias -file myCert.crt -keystore truststore.jks
```

For the client I use a small test program using jersey. I'm passing the path to the truststore as VM argument `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/truststore.jks`

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        try {
            String name = client.target("https://192.168.1.101:4443")
                    .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .get(String.class);

            System.out.println(name);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But however the self signed certificate is in the truststore, I always get the

```
  java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
exception
```

What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

The HTTPS certificate should contain the `SubjectAltName` extension which value should be the IP address (192.168.1.101 in your case) or the DNS name of the host.

Comment: It works when I put a domain in the CN instead of name and then use a local DNS Server which resolves the domain to my local IP address. But in that case I do not need to set SubjectAltName.